# Fuse Fabric: How to delete a configuration PID from a profile?

Tags: persistent, ident, fusefabric

I began modifying a profile and made some mistakes along the way.

Because of this I have PIDs in the profile which I'd like to delete entirely.

These can be seen in the `fabric:profile-display default` output shown at the bottom of this post.

They are:

`http:`

`patch.repositories=http:`

`org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories=http:`

I can't find the correct command to delete this. I've tried:

`config:delete org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories=http:`

which successfully completes. But the `default` profile still lists this pid.

I've also tried:

`fabric:profile-edit --delete -p org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories=http: default`

which fails with:

`Error executing command: String index out of range: -1`

This indicates a property path `/property` must be specified.

Appending simply `/` doesn't work either.

One more problem is that I have a pid with a seemingly empty name, as indicated by this line:

`PID:`                (nothing follows this output prefix).

#### Output of `fabric:profile-display default`:

```
Profile id: default
Version   : 1.0
Parents   : 
Associated Containers : 

Container settings
----------------------------
Repositories : 
        mvn:org.fusesource.fabric/fuse-fabric/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features

Features : 
        fabric-agent
        karaf
        fabric-jaas
        fabric-core

Agent Properties : 
          patch.repositories =  http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases,
                 http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea
          org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories =  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2,
                 http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases,
                 http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea,
                 http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release,
                 http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external,
                 http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases
          org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.defaultRepositories =   file:${karaf.home}/${karaf.default.repository}@snapshots,
                file:${karaf.home}/local-repo@snapshots


Configuration details
----------------------------
PID: 


PID: org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn
  org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.useFallbackRepositories false
  org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.disableAether true
  org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories ${profile:org.fusesource.fabric.agent/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories}
  org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.defaultRepositories ${profile:org.fusesource.fabric.agent/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.defaultRepositories}


PID: patch.repositories=http:


PID: org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories=http:


PID: http:


PID: org.fusesource.fabric.zookeeper
  zookeeper.url ${zk:root/ip}:2181
```

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could point the correct command(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the command-line code for `fabric:profile-edit` with `--delete` and unfortunately this function seems to be desgined for deleting key/value pairs from the PID, rather than deleting the PID itself.

(Here's the code for [ProfileEdit.java](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse/blob/master/fabric/fabric-commands/src/main/java/org/fusesource/fabric/commands/ProfileEdit.java) on github)

So basically you can use that command to "empty out" the PIDs, but not to remove them.

```
fabric:profile-edit --delete --pid mypid/mykey=myvalue myprofile
```

Knowing that this doesn't help you much, I asked my colleague who sits next to me (and is much smarter than me) and he recommended the following:

1. Enable fuse management console with `container-add-profile root fmc`
2. Opem fmc in a browser (mine is on localhost at port 8181), go to the `Profiles` page, choose your profile from the list
3. Go to the `Config Files` tab, find the PID you want to nuke and click the cross (X).

Et voila, the pid should be gone. Interested to know if this works for you, including on the "blank" profile...

Comment: Thanks for this response, vikingsteve. Yes I'm aware of the FMC route, but was surprised to discover there wasn't a console route to achieve this. Hopefully the same control is available in the new HawtIO interface (which looks awesome!) they're making available in JBoss Fuse 6.1 . There's an Early Access release for that already available, but the GA release is expected to be the end of September.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Fuse 6.2:

1) for property files (which become PID objects)

```
# create
profile-edit --resource foobar.properties default

# delete
profile-edit --delete --pid foobar default
```

2) for arbitrary files

```
# create
profile-edit --resource foobar.xml default


#delete
only via hawtio web console, see screenshot:
```

[image]